# element not interactable in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am developing an automated test robot with fobotramework (python)
I get this error message after I run it:
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome = 89.0.4389.72)
Here is the code:
`Click Element    //input[@id='fs_nyilatkozat_tudkut'] ScreenShot    FlipSwitchKijelolve.png Click Element    //button[@id='bt_benyujtas'] Screenshot    FlipSwitchKlikkAfterSleep.png`

What's wrong, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be element be hidden.

This link could be helpful. [robot framework forum](https://forum.robotframework.org/t/element-not-interactableexception-is-not-reachable-by-keyboard-issue/1882/3)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).